# Tag merge request for bigip

Tags: support, retag-request

Please merge tags "bigip" and "f5-big-ip". I can't imagine a situation where they would refer to disparate topics.

Answer (score 1):

Only 3 bigip tags, manually changed to f5-big-ip and suggested tag synonym.

Comment: Synonym needs 2 more votes: http://serverfault.com/tags/f5-big-ip/synonyms